# Should a bot help keep the OR chat room alive?

Tags: discussion, moderation, chat

[The main Operations Research chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94323/operations-research) has been frozen for inactivity in March. It was unfrozen again after a few days, so the acute danger is over.

Unfreezing it can be done by a moderator, but this is obviously a burden on the mod team which should perhaps be avoided.

I happen to operate [a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16115299/sloshy) which can take care of this chore (cough, [with *some* reliability)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/233626?m=55519735#55519735) but I'm hesitant to add it without consulting with the community.

Yea or nay? Should I go ahead and add it to the room?

Comment: See also https://github.com/tripleee/sloshy/issues/45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a mod, I'll vote "yes" -- although my sense is that most "chatting" comes from lengthy sequences of comments being turned into bespoke chats.

Comment: Thanks, I am interpreting this as having been granted approval by a mod. Of course, the bot can be removed from the room if the community comes up with a different opinion eventually.

Answer (score 4):

It's a "yes" from me. Sloshy is already keeping many rooms alive network-wide, for which I'm a room owner, and I find it very helpful.

Two things that I love most about Sloshy are listed below:

- Sloshy attempts to keep its posting of messages in the room to very close to the bare minimum needed for the room to remain open. Unlike GenericBot (which posts [approximately every 5 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0OLL.png)) and Shaun (which posts [approximately every 7 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aytO2.png)) and KennyBot (which can [sometimes post every few hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNGSe.png)), Sloshy will wait until **12 days** before posting any messages. This gives a 48 hours window before the room closes, in case something doesn't work and needs to be corrected.
- Sloshy is open source and on GitHub, and has had several network-wide users contribute to the YAML file. It's better maintained than some of the other bots which are privately maintained or don't have as much of an "open source culture".

Also, if the room has regular activity from non-bot users, you'll never even see that Sloshy was installed in the room, because Sloshy only ever does anything when the room has been inactive for around 12 days.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I'll note that you are involved as a stakeholder, though (albeit apparently only as an enthusiastic volunteer) by way of being the original requester for adding Sloshy to the room.